# What "disadvantages" will I have if I use CreateWindow*() instead of CreateDialog*() functions family?

Tags: windows, winapi, dialog, controls

What disadvantages will I have if I use CreateWindow*() instead of CreateDialog*() functions family to create controls in the long run? e.g., are there  things meant to work with dialogs and by using CreateWindow*() I would have hard time or even not make it work? for example, I've read people saying that I wouldn't be able to use TAB in controls if it wasn't a dialog, but I found out how do that by adding       IsDialogMessage() to main my loop, passing WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT() in dwExStyle from CreateWindowEx() and WS_TABSTOP in CreateWindowW(), so that worked.
The reason for this I'd like to create a property sheet(mimicking C#'s property grid), calling C routines/WINAPI, from another language, binary-compatible to C; but I'd like to define everything with code, without need of a resource script.

Comment: Official doc is probably relevant here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/about-dialog-boxes if you don't need dialog box features (templates, standard dialog box, etc) because of your context, you can use windows. There's a nice example of C/C+ property grid here https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/77957/Win-SDK-PropertyGrid-Made-Easy that's "just" a window.

Comment: Coding more but it seems not a problem for you if you want to define and control everything by yourself.